# Sort multi level nested list in groups and by level

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have a list:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', ['D', ['E', 'F'], 'G'], 'H']
```

and I want to turn this into:

```
[['E', 'F'], ['D', 'G'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'H']]
```

So basically I want the sublist on the deepest level of the list to come first in the new list and then counting down the level the remaining sublists.
This should work with any nested list.

If there are two sublists on the same level, then it doesn't really matter which one comes first.

```
['A', 'B', 'C', ['D', ['E', 'F'], 'G'], ['H', 'I', 'J']]

[['E', 'F'], ['D', 'G'], ['H', 'I', 'J'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'H']] #this is fine
[['E', 'F'], ['H', 'I', 'J'], ['D', 'G'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'H']] #this too
```

I thought of first using a function to determine on what level the deepest sublist is, but then again I don't know how to access items in a list based on their level or if that's even possible.

Been tinkering around this for far too long now and I think my head just gave up, hope someone can assist me with this problem!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a relatively straight-forward solution:

```
def sort_depth(d):
    def dlists(obj, dep=0):
        for x in filter(list.__instancecheck__, obj):
            yield from dlists(x, dep-1)
        yield [x for x in obj if not isinstance(x, list)], dep
    return [x for x, y in sorted(dlists(d), key=lambda p: p[1])]
        

>>> [*sort_depth([[1, [2]], [3, [4]]])]
[[2], [4], [1], [3], []]

>>> [*sort_depth(['A', 'B', 'C', ['D', ['E', 'F'], 'G'], 'H'])]
[['E', 'F'], ['D', 'G'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'H']]
```

The approach:

1. Collect all the sublists and annotate them with their (negative) nesting level, e.g. `(['E', 'F'], -2)`
2. Sort them by their nesting level
3. Extract the lists back from the sorted data

Comment: thanks alot for the quick solution!! this one seems to work better than the other! saved me lots of trouble, I'll mark urs :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
def sort_depth(d, c = 0):
  r = {0:[], 1:[]}
  for i in d:
     r[not isinstance(i, list)].append(i)
  yield from [i for j in r[0] for i in sort_depth(j, c+1)]
  yield (c, r[1])
 
def result(d):
   return [b for _, b in sorted(sort_depth(d), key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True) if b]

print(result(['A', 'B', 'C', ['D', ['E', 'F'], 'G'], 'H']))
print(result(['A', 'B', 'C', ['D', ['E', 'F'], 'G'], ['H', 'I', 'J']]))
print(result([[1, [2]], [3, [4]]]))
```

Output:

```
[['E', 'F'], ['D', 'G'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'H']]
[['E', 'F'], ['D', 'G'], ['H', 'I', 'J'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
[[2], [4], [1], [3]]
```

Comment: This does not work. Try `sort_depth([[1, [2]], [3, [4]]])` and you will see the flaw.

Comment: You are a god, thank you so much! I'll mark ur answer in a few minutes!!

Comment: @mimookies Have you tried the example. THis does not sort by nesting level. It will always go back up the same sublist depth-first. It only works on your sample input by accident.

Comment: @schwobaseggl hey and yeah I noticed that too, I'm guessing it goes through the first item first and then continues with the next one... not ideal, but it's helping me for now. pls lmk if anyone has a solution for the flaw tho!

Comment: Well, the output for `[[1, [2]], [3, [4]]]` is `[[2], [1], [4], [3], []]` which is mighty dubious with  `[1]` coming before `[4]` despite being clearly less deeply nested.

Comment: @schwobaseggl yup tried it on some other nested lists, it seems like the function treats same level sublists a bit weirdly..
Ajax1234 u got any idea what to do there? 
['A', 'B', 'C', ['D', ['E', 'F'], 'G'], ['H', 'I', ['J', ['K', 'L']]]] <- this would be another example that doesnt work as it should

Comment: Now the output is still missing the empty top-level.

Comment: ... and still doesn't handle levels beyond 2 correctly: `sort_depth([[1, [2, [5]]], [3, [4, [6]]]])`

Comment: @mimookies Sorry for the late response, please see my recent edit.

Comment: hey Ajax1234 thanks for going through it again! works the way i wanted to now and sorry for the spam in the replies 
I'll remember to upvote urs once i got enough rep!

Comment: @mimookies Glad to help!